# Groovy Install Binary package

Tags: groovy

I have downloaded groovy from following website https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/groovy/groovy-all/4.0.5-SNAPSHOT/

After downloading I moved my zip package under my Redhat system /home/user/groovy folder then i execute the unzip command to /home/user/groovy/groovy/4.0.5-SNAPSHOT

```
export GROOVY_HOME=/home/user/groovy/groovy-4.0.5
```

I have created simple hello world script

```
!#/home/user/groovy/groovy-4.0.5
println 'Hello World!'
```

its showing the error groovy command not found. can you please some one help me on this.

Comment: is the `groovy` executable in the main folder of `groovy-4.0.5`, not in `groovy-4.0.5/bin` or something?

Comment: it should be like this: `!#/home/user/groovy/groovy-4.0.5/bin/groovy`

Comment: i have smiler approach , i have configured groovy_home in my linux box but while running script i'm getting error.  /home/user/groovy/CreateProjectAutomatorTemplate.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class CliBuilder
 @ line 9, column 11.
   def cli = new CliBuilder (usage:'createProjectAutomater.groovy [options]')
             ^

/home/user/groovy/CreateProjectAutomatorTemplate.groovy: 89: unable to resolve class XmlSlurper
 @ line 89, column 32.
           def componentFileXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(componentsFile)

Comment: Hi @ daggett, I can able to run the Hello World! program now.